# How threads are executed in the memory in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning about **Thread in Java**. I was trying to fetch which thread is running. But, I am not able to understand the order of the output.

Following is my code

```
public class practice extends Thread {

public void run(){  
      for(int i=1;i<4;i++){  
         
        System.out.println(i); 
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
      }  
     
     }  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    practice t1=new practice();  
      practice t2=new practice();  
      practice t3=new practice();  
      
      t1.start();  
      t2.start(); 
      t3.start(); 
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
Thread-1
2
Thread-1
3
Thread-1
Thread-0
2
Thread-0
3
Thread-0
Thread-2
2
Thread-2
3
Thread-2
```

Can anyone help me out in understand the order of output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: I expect that the **Thread -0** must be in the output first instead of **Thread-1**

Comment: Can I have a brief explanation of the output why is the output in such an order

Comment: You can't enforce a sequence of execution for threads. If you want sequential execution, then why are you using threads ?

Comment: Thank for the information I didn't thought about that

Comment: By the way, in modern Java we do not extend `Thread` and do not manage threads manually. The Executors framework was invented to relieve us of that tricky chore. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). Instead of extending `Thread`, write your task as a `Runnable` or `Callable` to be submitted to an executor service produced by the `Executors` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Threads**, by their nature, are *concurrent to each other*. This means, that two (or more) threads compete for the same resource (CPU) when they are executed at the same time, and CPU switches itself from executing one to another in a random-to-you (unpredictable) order. You can't and won't know to which execution path (Thread) your CPU and OS architecture will decide to jump. Moreover, in some languages, this may be a question of the **OS architecture**, in some - the question of **CPU architecture** only, and in some - question of **both**. It depends on how that language's architecture manages threads.

Note, that even if two threads are *parallel* - i.e. they execute in parallel on two different cores - you still are unable to predict which core will execute instruction first.

Because of the points above, you may be getting a different order of execution of your code, *each time* you run it.

Comment: If I change my device will the order of output will be different?

Comment: @SumitSingh You **cannot predict the order** of output. The scheduling of the threads on CPU cores by the JVM and host OS cannot be determined, and may vary on every run.

Comment: Might be, might not. It's different even on the same device as you see. What does this information give you anyways? I think I described your problem in quite of details.. you can't predict the execution order of 2 or more threads. You want to go into physics of transistors, CPU architecture or OS Kernel? I assume it's not going to increase your Java or Programming knowledge.. and this is definitely not a place for those discussions. I hope this helps.

Comment: I beleive this platform is for any sort of discussion related to any problem and queries related to programming

Comment: I have clearly stated, that `if your question goes to the CPU architecture` it's not programming anymore.. at least, it's not high-level programming in which you're interested. And this platform is programming-centric.

Answer (score 1):

First .. please format your code for better visibility.Then use java naming convention.To find them out look [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).
It seems that you are a beginner in Threads and not understanding them in the first glance is completely OK.The unexpected order is related to OS scheduling and the concept of executing **instructions**  and not methods concurrently, this mean that concurrent execution does not mean that **run** method will run concurrently, that means that everything (every instruction) in that method can/will run concurrently.
Just keep learning Threads are (maybe) the most difficult area of Java but also the most interesting.

Comment: Thanks, from the next time I will take care of the format.