# Java threads not all executing concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have so code that looks something like

```
public final void startThreads(){
    for(Elephant el: elephants)
        el.start();
    for(Mouse m: mice)
        m.start();
}
```

where elephants and mice are linked lists of threads with my run method in Elephant looking like

```
public void run(){
    while (numMiceOnSpace() <= 2){
        this.move();
    }
    ...
```

and my run method in Mouse looking like

```
public void run(){
    while(field.elephants.size() > 0) {
        this.move();
    }
}
```

Everytime an animal moves, I print to the console, but I'm getting console output that looks like it's making one animal move a bunch before switching to another one, and it doesn't look like the elephants are moving at all

```
Mouse 2 to 363 578
Mouse 2 to 364 577
Mouse 2 to 363 576
Mouse 2 to 363 576
Mouse 2 to 362 576
Mouse 2 to 362 575
Mouse 2 to 363 575
Mouse 2 to 362 576
Mouse 2 to 362 576
Mouse 4 to 651 293
Mouse 4 to 650 294
Mouse 4 to 649 295
Mouse 4 to 648 294
Mouse 4 to 647 295
Mouse 4 to 647 296
Mouse 4 to 648 296
Mouse 4 to 647 296
Mouse 4 to 646 295
Mouse 4 to 647 295
```

I figure this could maybe have to do something with how many threads my computer can run at once? I don't know. Is there a way to give up priority of a thread at the end of every loop inside the run method or something? There's 5 elephant threads and 7 mice threads.

---

The biggest problem is that I never see any of the elephants moving, it looks like the mice are hogging the CPU completely.

Comment: We are going to see more code than this. It looks like your elephant threads depend on mice threads running and your move threads depend on elephant threads. That just seems like a potential deadlock to me. It also could just be incorrect logic.

Comment: As a comment: just because threads are started does not mean that any "fairness" in execution is guaranteed. It is up to the JVM (and probably the OS) when to scheudle which execution on which core. If one wants to guarantee that, for examples, all animals move once, before any animal moves again, then one hasto implement additional synchronization.

Comment: @BaileyKocin Sure, it's at this github repo https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/elephant-mouse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How threads are executed in the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857956/how-threads-are-executed-in-the-memory)

Comment: May I suggest that for learning purposes, try just one elephant and one mouse thread. Then, once you've got that working, increase by one thread, get that working, and so on.

Comment: Try printing `fields.elephants.size()`.  Unless you are using a collection with concurrency support (like [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html)), it’s possible those threads will never see changes in its size.  See [this example in the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at it with high time-resolution, then you will see the von-Neumann-Architecture nature of processes and threads in CPUs. Per CPU core there can only be one computation at a time. So you should see different behaviour when you run it on more cores.

You say that you already have established that each `Animal` is moving, so it looks like the threads are started allright.

Would it not suffice to have all animals located at coordinates and have only **one thread** move them around in a global time-dimension?
This thread would check once per clock interval each animal's location and update them according to some logic. This connects all animals to a global clock.

Or is it the goal of you project to have individual clocks for each animal?
Then indeed you need a lot of synchronization between the threads, once animals interact.

Comment: The goal is to have all the threads working

Comment: ok, running your program from the github site again.
Did you see the 
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 ...
 at Project1.Elephant.numMiceOnSpace(Elephant.java:15)




These come in the beginning and are quickly flushed away with sysouts.
I think your program needs help on more than one front.
We should leave the "elephants not moving" problem out of this entry, since it seems an altogether different problem.

Comment: I didn't see that no, it was flushed out before I could see it