# How to ensure execution order of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

This is a simplified version of the problem. Given `n` number of threads, each printing a constant number all the time. For example, `Thread-1` should always print `1`, `Thread-2` should always print `2` and so on...

How to ensure, the threads are executed in order i.e. the output should be as below:

```
Thread-1: 1
Thread-2: 2
Thread-3: 3
.
.
.
Thread-n: n
```

I have a naïve solution to do it through `wait()`/`notify()` but I guess there might be a better solution than that. Perhaps, using `Semaphore` maybe? I don't know.

**Update**:

Based on the answers received, I think I was not very clear. There are some constraints:

1. All threads should start at once (assume we don't really have control on that)
2. Once all the threads start, there should be some sort of communication between the threads to execute in order.

Comment: You can chain the threads, each thread with a link to the next one. Each thread starts with a wait synchronized on itself, and once it wakes up and does its job, it notifies the next one and waits again. This solution requires no shared objects.

Comment: If a thread dies before notifying the next there will be deadlock

Comment: If something has to be executed in order, using threads is the wrong approach.

Comment: @BurakSerdar That won't work. The most obvious way to show why it won't work is to consider spurious wakeups. You have to store the state *somewhere* and that object has to be shared.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz. Good point. I didn't know about spurious wakeups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How threads are executed in the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857956/how-threads-are-executed-in-the-memory)

Comment: Just expanding on what @NathanHughes said, The whole purpose of threads is to allow things to happen _concurrently_ in your program instead of forcing them to happen sequentially. If you _want_ things to happen sequentially, then all you have to do is do everything in the same thread.

Comment: @Learner, What do you mean by communicating between threads and why is it necessary? Can't we use a queue to solve the problem? There are a lot of ways to solve this problem through a queue or java builtin concurrent execution scheduling utilities...again, pls, explain the reason between "why communication between threads is so necessary?"

Answer (score 1):

This sequentially execution of thread can be handled beautifully using `Thread.join()` method. To handle it properly, you may have to create `MyRunnable`(or, use any name you prefer) which implements `Runnable` interface. Inside `MyRunnable`, you can inject a `parent` `Thread`, and call `parent.join()` at top of `MyRunnable.run()` method. The code is given below:

```java
public class SequentialThreadsTest {

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        static int objCount; // to keep count of sequential object

        private int objNum;
        private Thread parent; // keep track of parent thread
        
        MyRunnable(Thread parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.objNum = objCount + 1;
            objCount += 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(parent != null) {
                    parent.join();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread-" + objNum + ": " + objNum);

            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // do something else

            } finally {
                // do what you need to do when thread execution is finished
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        
        Thread parentThread = null;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable(parentThread));
            thread.start();

            parentThread = thread;
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Thread-1: 1
Thread-2: 2
Thread-3: 3
Thread-4: 4
Thread-5: 5
Thread-6: 6
Thread-7: 7
Thread-8: 8
Thread-9: 9
Thread-10: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified many details, but if you only want serializable thread execution you can wait for previous thread to finish and then print. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int index = i;
            Thread previousThread = thread;
            thread = new Thread(() -> {
                if (previousThread != null) {
                    try {
                        previousThread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(index);
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a queue - this will do exactly what you want. Simply change the value of n to however many threads you have, and add all the threads sequentially (only once). If ever you want to stop the threads from executing, all you have to do is add `end` to the queue. Obviously, for a larger project, you will need to modify this code a little bit (I would recommend replacing the `main` method with a class initializer and pass the `LinkedBlockingQueue` as a pre-built argument)

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;



public class HelloWorld{
    
    private static int n = 2;
    private static LinkedBlockingQueue<Thread> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(n+1);
    
    static Thread a = new Thread(()->{
            System.out.print("a");
        
        });
        
    static Thread b = new Thread(()->{
            System.out.print("b");
        
        });    
        
    static Thread end = new Thread(()->{
            break_ = true;
        
        }); 


    
    public static final int END = 20;//this and the counter are just here so the code doesn't run forever
    public static volatile int i = 0;
    public static volatile boolean break_ = false;
    public static void main(String []args){
        
        queue.add(a);
        queue.add(b);
        //queue.add(end);
        
        
        outerloop:
        while(true){
            
            Thread toBeRun = queue.poll();
            try{
                toBeRun.run();
                queue.add(toBeRun);
                i++;
                if(i>=END || break_){//i>=END does not need to be here, it's just to stop it from running forever in this example
                    break;
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                break;
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
        
     }
}
```

Note: This uses java 8 lambdas. If you're using an older version of java, you will need to create the threads using the `run` method.

Comment: Your code example does not create any threads. It creates some `Thread` instances, but a `Thread` is not a thread. A `Thread` is the handle that your program uses to create and manage a "native" thread. The native thread does not get created until you call the `Thread` instance's `start()` method.